# Ruby search and replace a string which contains a forward slash

Tags: ruby

i'm a newbie to ruby and i am trying to replace a string using gsub which contains forward slash,

```
background: url(../images/body-bg-sky.jpg) repeat-x center top #fff;
```

with

```
background: black
```

i used below code for search and replacing the string but it did not work

```
File.write(f = "changes.css", File.read(f).gsub(/background: url(..\b/images\b/body-bg-sky.jpg) repeat-x center top #fff;/,"background: black;"))
```

please help me with the issue

Comment: Please use code formatting.

Comment: and spelling and grammar

Comment: Hi i am trying to replace the string new_contents = text.gsub(/background: url(../images / body - bg - sky.jpg) repeat - x center top# fff;
/,"background: black;")

Comment: the string is " background: url(../images / body - bg - sky.jpg) repeat - x center top# fff; "  with "background: black;"

Answer (score 2):

Special characters such as forward slashes, dots, and parentheses need to be escaped with a backslash when using regular expressions.

if `str` is the string in question, this should work:

```
str.sub(/background: .*\/.*$/, 'background: black')
```

I recommend [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) for helping you learn how to use regular expressions.